# Поиск коммитов по имени измененного в коммите файла

Tags: git, git-log

Можно ли найти и вывести коммиты в которых изменялся(добавлялся/удалялся/правился) определенный файл(т.е. по его имени)? Например, мне нужно найти коммит, где был удален qwerty.cpp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839398

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо!